# What is The song playing in my hero academia season 4 episode 12 at 11:40?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

Can someone please help me find the song used in the episode (12) of season 4. It starts at the 11:41 mark in, It is the part where Deku land his blow, on mutated overhaul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The song is [I'm Seriously Going to Crush you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQCd2HBgVcE)